# How do I change the color of the visual studio code toolbar?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, terminal

> hello, my question is the following, in the new visual studio code update, for Ubuntu Linux, the toolbar (attached photo) we can see that it is white, and it was to know if it can be changed to black as it was in previous updates, and how is it done? ... thanks

[image: I attach the image]

Answer (score 7):

For the people who are looking for a new solution:
In the latest version of VSCode, you can add

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
```

to your settings.json file and it should use your vscode theme for the border/titlebar

Answer (score 0):

The [GTK Dark Title Bar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fkrull.gtk-dark-titlebar&ssr=false#overview) could be the solution to your problems.

I also want to leave some more references to the various issues opened on the official vscode repo in the past years about this problem so that you can give a reading and get an idea of what happened.

- [#16363 - Allow to change the background color of menu bar (Windows & some Linux)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/16363)
- [#11979 - Support dark theme in Gnome](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11979)
- [#30031 - Add a way to choose theme variant (Gnome dark/light theme)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30031)
- [#45968 - Set the _GTK_THEME_VARIANT X11 property on top-level window to use "dark" theme on Gnome](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45968)

Comment: hello thank you very much for the help .. I really did not know the name .... thank you very much again men

Comment: @Simon_molina.T No problem!

Comment: @Simon_molina.T as common practice, if you could mark the answer that respond to your question as solved would be great!